# Exiting from the cycle of rebirth according to Saivism

Tags: shiva

In the Buddhist tradition , starting from Gautama, The Buddha opened a way to practically exit from Samsara.
What about the Saivism? It is said that Shiva can grant to the devotee liberation from the circle of existence. What are the most important passages of the scriptures where is stated?

Comment: Shiva gave 112 ways in Vijyanbhairava Tantra which is a compilation of conversation between devi shakti and shiva himself.